# Inserting a dotted line between articles

Tags: views

Can anyone help on how I can insert a dotted line between articles? Currently I created it in view Global Custom text field using horizontal rule `<hr>` which gives a solid line, but I need dotted lines instead. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) questions about CSS are off topic here so this needs to be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **CSS** instead, adding a bottom border to the articles:

```
article { border-bottom: 1px dotted black; }
```

If you also want to hide the bottom border of the last element, just add:

```
article:last-of-type { border-bottom: none; }
```

It is possible depending on the theme you are using that the article contains `first` or `last` inside class tag.